# Running numbers for comments

Tags: numbering, environments, enumerate

I wish to have comment 1, comment 2 as running numbers, and for each reviewer I want to restart the running number, is there a good way to achieve this? Following is how the pdf currently looks, and its latex (you can see that I hard code the number in the latex).

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[usenames]{color}

    \begin{document}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{2ex}


    \title{Change Summary}

    \author{This is author}

    \maketitle


    We are thankful for the valuable and insightful comments from referees.
    These comments have helped us to improve our work.
    We have fixed the typos and language problems based on the reviews.
    The rest of the comments are addressed in the following.

    \section*{Reviewer 1}
    \textbf{Comment 1}:
    This is comment 1

    \textbf{Reply}: This is reply 1
    .

    \textbf{Comment 2}: This is comment 2

    \textbf{Reply}:
    This is reply 2

    \section*{Reviewer 2}
    \textbf{Comment 1}: This is comment 1

    \textbf{Reply}: This is Reply 1

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I improved the solution, with just one counter

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}

\newcounter{CommentReply}[section]


\newcommand{\CommentReply}[2]{%
  \addtocounter{CommentReply}{1}%
  \textbf{Comment \theCommentReply:} #1 

  \textbf{Reply \theCommentReply:} #2

}

\begin{document}

\pretocmd{\section}{\setcounter{CommentReply}{0}}{}{}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}




    \title{Change Summary}

    \author{This is author}

    \maketitle


    We are thankful for the valuable and insightful comments from referees.
    These comments have helped us to improve our work.
    We have fixed the typos and language problems based on the reviews.
    The rest of the comments are addressed in the following.

    \section*{Reviewer 1}

    \CommentReply{This is comment 1}{This is reply 1}


    \CommentReply{This is comment 2}{This is reply 2}

    \section*{Reviewer 2}

    \CommentReply{This is comment 1}{This is reply 1}


    \CommentReply{This is comment 2}{This is reply 2}



    \end{document}
```

**Quick and dirty solution:**

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[usenames]{color}

    \newcounter{CommentReply}[section]
    \newcommand{\CommentReply}[2]{%
      \refstepcounter{CommentReply}%

      \textbf{Comment \theCommentReply:}  #1%

      \textbf{Reply \theCommentReply:}   #2%

      }

    \begin{document}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{2ex}




    \title{Change Summary}

    \author{This is author}

    \maketitle


    We are thankful for the valuable and insightful comments from referees.
    These comments have helped us to improve our work.
    We have fixed the typos and language problems based on the reviews.
    The rest of the comments are addressed in the following.

    \section*{Reviewer 1}

    \CommentReply{This is comment 1}{This is reply 1}


    \CommentReply{This is comment 2}{This is reply 2}

    \setcounter{CommentReply}{0}% 
    \section*{Reviewer 2}

    \CommentReply{This is comment 1}{This is reply 1}


    \CommentReply{This is comment 2}{This is reply 2}



    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With several counters a solution reads

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{reviewer}\setcounter{reviewer}{0}
\newcounter{comment}\setcounter{comment}{0}
\newcounter{reply}\setcounter{reply}{0}
\@addtoreset{comment}{reviewer}
\@addtoreset{reply}{reviewer}
\def\reviewer{\stepcounter{reviewer}\section*{Reviewer \arabic{reviewer}}}
\def\comment{\stepcounter{comment}\textbf{Comment \arabic{comment}:}}
\def\reply{\stepcounter{reply}\textbf{Reply \arabic{reply}:}}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\setlength{\parskip}{2ex} please do not set \parskip, use package setspace instead
\title{Change Summary}
\author{This is author}
\maketitle
We are thankful for the valuable and insightful comments from referees.
These comments have helped us to improve our work.
We have fixed the typos and language problems based on the reviews.
The rest of the comments are addressed in the following.
\reviewer
\comment\ This is comment 1

\reply\ This is reply 1.

\comment\ This is comment 2

\reply\ This is reply 2

\reviewer
\comment\ This is comment 1

\reply\ This is Reply 1
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

You create a counter "within" a counter.  `chngectr` might be just the trick here.  It is worth looking at.

`\newcounter{reviewer}`   %create new counter reviewer

`\counterwithin{comment}{reviewer}`   %  create comment witnin reviewer

Answer (score 2):

Here you can also add labels for `\ref`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{reviewer}
\newcounter{comment}[reviewer] % comment is reset when reviewer is stepped
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@comment{\thereviewer.}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\reviewer}{%
  \refstepcounter{reviewer}%
  \section*{Reviewer \thereviewer}
}
\newcommand{\comment}{%
  \par\addvspace{2ex}\noindent
  \refstepcounter{comment}%
  \textbf{Comment \thecomment:}\enspace\ignorespaces
}
\newcommand{\reply}{%
  \par\addvspace{1ex}
  \noindent\textbf{Reply:}\enspace\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}


\title{Change Summary}

\author{This is author}

\maketitle


We are thankful for the valuable and insightful comments from referees.
These comments have helped us to improve our work.
We have fixed the typos and language problems based on the reviews.
The rest of the comments are addressed in the following.

\reviewer
\comment
This is comment 1

\reply
This is reply 1


\comment\label{rev1-comm2}
This is comment 2

\reply
This is reply 2


\reviewer
\comment
This is comment 1

\reply
This is Reply 1 (see \ref{rev1-comm2})

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to say

```
\renewcommand\p@comment{Reviewer~\thereviewer, Comment~}
```

instead of the code above; in this case the last reply would be printed as

[image]