# What documentclass/template should I use for non sectioned essays?

Tags: templates, document-classes

I have looked for different templates but most of them are concerned with papers, theses, books etc. But I am wondering if there is a specific one for simple essays, because (as an example) using the minimal document-class is discouraged.

Comment: Any `article` (`scrartcl`, `amsart`, ...) just with no `\section` present would do the job, wouldn't it?

Comment: @tohecz Indeed, that is what I have been doing formerly. I am just wondering whether other templates exist, because to me it seems like a relatively common requirement.

Comment: In addition to tohecz's comment: I would use article classes, together with geometry package and load some different font to make it more 'literature' appealing.

Comment: Perhaps the content behind this link might help: http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/essays

Comment: @Ruben: Perhaps you should clearify in your question which features you request from such an essay layout/class? Otherwise it is some kind of *make an educated guess*

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I had a look at that website before posting, but they refer to *sectioned* essays, as opposed to my question. As for your other comment, 'essay' is quite broad, it could range from economic commentaries to literature essays.

Comment: @Ruben: About the sectioned essays: Sorry, I did not check it. As for the 'essay' comment of yours: What kind of essay do have in mind? Economic commentaries, literature, ...?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Simply general responses to stimuli (in the form of questions etc). But I am satisfied with the answers, as my question was merely an enquiry if there was a definite template, which I now believe there isn't.

Comment: Something like in here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174833/running-numbers-for-comments/174835#174835? Perhaps it is possible to use the standard classes and add some environments for your special request